# How to remove someone's google account off my phone when asked to verify

Tags: google-account, google, 2-step-verification

We are going through custody battles atm, and I allowed my child to take her phone to her mother's, in case she needed me or felt unsafe. Her mom took the phone, removed my google account, added hers and make it to where it needs to verify the account before I can make any changes. So now she can control all the parental locks, send messages when she shouldn't be, ect. How can I remove her account and replace mine since they are my phones to begin with?

Comment: Please describe the phone model and operating system.

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically trying to do is unlock the device to re-establish control and that will be done first through Google's "find  my device" and is that doesn't work just unlock the device through factory reset and use FRP bypass if you need to!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, accounts, Google, select the account to remove, tap 3 dot menu, select remove account.
U maybe asked to enter device's pin or pattern.
The process may be different in different versions of Android